# Android Parse SDK not picking up deviceToken

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have a self hosted parse-server, when i create a new android user the device token in the database doesn't get set. as a note i am using fcm for push

has anyone got FCM to work with parse server?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible. Reading from the [Pushwoosh website](https://www.pushwoosh.com/parse-android-push/) who replaced Parse (since Parse was acquired by Facebook):

> GCM Android Push notifications, which are being replaced by FCM now,
>   require you to create a Project in Google Developer Console and use
>   your own Sender ID and Server Key. In order to simplify the
>   configuration process, Parse offered to use their internal Sender ID
>   and Server Key to send push notifications. If you used the default
>   Parse Android push configuration settings and didn’t register your own
>   GCM sender ID and GCM Server key, all your GCM tokens belong to Parse.
>   This is what we never did at Pushwoosh and we always asked our users
>   to register their own GCM Sender ID and GCM Server Key. What is
>   important to understand is that Parse will never share his Private
>   Server Key as it would compromise all Android push tokens from any
>   Parse-based project.
>
> What Does It Mean?
>
> **It means that you can use the default Sender ID and API key registered
>   in Parse only to send push notifications via Parse. You can’t migrate
>   these device tokens to another push service since you don’t have
>   Parse’s Server Key**. In that way these tokens can be considered gone.
>   The only solution – you should start collecting new push tokens as
>   soon as you can.

In short you have to use only one.

Answer (score 0):

i actually found a solution.

via https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android#firebase-notifications

so effectively there is a fix, parse uses the old way of collecting the token via gcm request token method, fcm now auto calls for a token at the time the application first installs. this creates a mismatch hence parse doesn't actually work well with fcm sdk.

but you can actually use them together and although both gcm and fcm get different tokens both these tokens actually point to the same device. i have tested this and it does work well using both tokens from a private parse server.

you must ensure you are using the "ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" or either you use a custom class as the link says. thing is you "FirebaseMessagingService" class and you custom gcm receiver class will both fire when a message comes in. so what i did was receive messages with the FirebaseMessagingService class and filter as required.